# Prepend optional attribute in angular ui-router URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to have an optional attribute at the beginning of the url in ui-router? If so, how?

I want to achieve sth like this:

```
.state('events',{
    url: '(/city:)?/events/:id'
    ...
})
```

So **"city"** would be optional.

Thank you for any input whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably bad practice to have two separate routes point to the same state, but nothing is keeping you from creating two different states that use the same resolutions/controller/template.

```
$stateProvider
.state('state1', {
  url: "/:city/events/:id",
  templateUrl: "partials/events.html",
  controller: eventsCtrl
})
.state('state2', {
  url: "/events/:id",
  templateUrl: "partials/events.html",
  controller: eventsCtrl
});

function eventsCtrl($scope){
  // shared controller
}
```

Again, this is probably bad practice but I can't think of a better solution

Comment: Yeah that is why I am asking this question, cause I want to avoid this... But yeah fair point. If no one knows better solution I guess this is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to answer the similar (if not same) here:

[Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310)

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQoyofkSCkhJdezXMlyQ?p=preview), solving the issue for a **`language`** instead of for a **`city`** *(but the concept is the same)*

so, we would/should introduce some super state 'root'.

> In our case, we can even use some regex to limit allowed values - **because it would be hard to guess what is `city` and what is `events`**

```
.state('root', {
    url: '/{city:(?:Prague|Bristol|Denver)}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    params: {lang : { squash : true, value: 'Prague' }}
})
```

What is important here is the setting **`params : {}`**. It says, that the default value is 'Prague' - so that would be the city if none is selected. What is also important - **it should be squashed, skipped if there is a match with 'Prague' param value**:

```
params: {lang : { squash : true, value: 'Prague' }}
```

Now, we can introduce some nested state(s) which would declare 'root' as their parent:

```
.state('events',{
    parent: 'root',
    url: '/events/:id'
    ...
})
```

Check the working example (with a language instead of city) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQoyofkSCkhJdezXMlyQ?p=preview). For more details see the original [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31470320/1679310)

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why you wan't do it in a standard `ui-router` state setup.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDWK0BvnLi6uRPcB3BMd?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

      .state('state1', {
        url: ':city/events/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsController'
      })

      .state('state2', {
        url: ':abc/cities/:x/:y',
        templateUrl: 'partials/cities.html',
        controller: 'CitiesController'
      });

  })

  .controller('EventsController', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    angular.extend($scope, $stateParams);

  })

  .controller('CitiesController', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    angular.extend($scope, $stateParams);

  });
```

Comment: Does it support `www.xyz.com/abc/cities/y/z` and also `www.xyz.com/cities/y/z`?. I don't think it does...

Comment: Of course it does, check the demo again, I added a new state definition.