# optional parameters in ui.router url

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I am trying to show the same view regardless of whether the **`:id`** parameter is set in the url.  I have this but the **`/cases`** route doesn't seem to work without the **`:id`**.

```
.state 'messages',
  url: '/cases',
  views:
    '':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages.html',
      controller: 'MessagesCtrl'
    'ticketList@messages':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages/list.html'
    'ticketComments@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/comments.html'
    'ticketDetail@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/detail.html',
.state 'messages.id',
  url: '/cases/:id',
  views:
    '':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages.html',
      controller: 'MessagesCtrl'
    'ticketList@messages':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages/list.html'
    'ticketComments@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/comments.html'
    'ticketDetail@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/detail.html',
```

Comment: try using one route with query parameters `url: '/cases?id'` instead. you can still access them inside the controller with `$stateParams.id`

Comment: you use nested states, so you should remove "/cases" from your "messages.id" state: url: '/:id'. Otherwhise your url looks like: "/cases/cases/:id"

Comment: also you could remove your second state (because you use the same templates and controllers) and change your first "url" to: url: '/cases[/:id]'

Comment: Tj Gienger, thank you, you saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there - just child inherits **`url`** from its parent. So to make just cases working, we should do:

```
.state 'messages',
  url: '/cases',
  ....
.state 'messages.id',
  // url: '/cases/:id', // instead of this
  url: '/:id',          // we need this
```

And we can do even more, e.g. use **`params :{}`** to define more precise settings. Check these for example:

- [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)
- [Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310)
- [Prepend optional attribute in angular ui-router URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837507/1679310)
- [Angular UI-Router more Optional Parameters in one State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230421/1679310)