# Option url path UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

In my angular application, I am making heavy use of nested states with UI-Router.

I am trying to create a parent state that determines the locale of the application based on a URL that has an optional locale path.

- For Spanish `www.website.com/es/search`
- For English `www.website.com/search`

the **`'/es'`** is required for Spanish, but English is implied by the parameter missing and I would prefer to not have the **`'/en'`**.

I want any child state of this one to inherit that locale value.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('localization', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/:locale?',
        params: {
            locale: { value: 'en' }
        }
    })
    .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        parent: 'localization'
    });
```

I'd like to be able to use `$stateParams.locale` in any of the child states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost the same Q & A: [Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310) or [another here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837507/1679310)

The solution is to create root state like this:

```
.state('localization', {
    url: '/{locale:(?:en|es|cs)}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    params: {locale : { squash : true, value: 'en' }}
})
```

Any child state then can just use this as a parent:

```
.state('home', {
    parent: 'localization', // parent will do the magic
    url: "/",
    ...
})
.state('activity', {
    parent: 'localization',
    ...
```

[Check it here](http://localization), where is also fully working plunker

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir!