# mapping similar urls to same states based on an optional parameter (angular-ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I have the below states, which I would like to map to the same routes, which would then have a parameter.

```
/en/live/
/en/


/en/live/football
/en/football
```

Basically, the 'live' part needs to be stored in some kind of variable.  I've tried something like:

```
$stateProvider.state('language.live-lobby', {
    url: "/en/{liveStatus:live|}/football"
}
```

However, it does not let you specify an empty parameter.  Basically, with the above state, `/en/live/football` matches while `/en/football` doesn't.  If that worked, I could then read the `liveStatus` parameter.

Is it possible, without having to define multiple states?  I would like to avoid having to create multiple states, as they all share the same information like `views`, `data` & `resolve`?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyzkLNIvEC7LEmzf0ADw?p=preview)

Based on these:

- [Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310)
- [Prepend optional attribute in angular ui-router URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837507/1679310)

we can use this state def:

```
.state('language.live-lobby', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  //url: "/en/{liveStatus:live|}/football",
  url: "/{lang:(?:en|cz|de)}" +
       "/{liveStatus:(?:live|podcast)}" +
       "/{sport:(?:football|golf)}",
  params: {
    lang:       { squash: true, value: 'en' },
    liveStatus: { squash: true, value: 'live' },
    sport:      { squash: true, value: 'football' },
  }
})
```

All these links would work as expected:

```
  // these follow defaults
  <a href="#/en/live/">
  <a href="#/en/">
  <a href="#/en/live/football">
  <a href="#/en/football">

  //here we pass some non default
  <a href="#/cz/podcast/">
  <a href="#/cz/">
  <a href="#/cz/podcast/golf">
  <a href="#/cz/golf">
```

Check [it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyzkLNIvEC7LEmzf0ADw?p=preview)

Comment: The Plunker works, however strangely enough for my code it is not working.  When it is not left blank, the route matches.  When it is left blank, the ui-router matches no state. I'm trying to determine what could be different.

Comment: Sad... if you could adjust my plunker to "break" it .. I am ready to assist, if I could... but now I do not know what to add

Comment: If I manage to determine what is breaking it, I would.  Is there any official documentation on the 'squash' parameter?